# What is PHP track_errors?

Tags: cpanel, php

I was just glancing through my Cpanel's php.ini EZConfig (basically php.ini; it just allows me to change some settings in php.ini through Cpanel) and noticed track_errors.

Can someone tell me what this means, I have searched the php website and Google and cannot find out what it means exactly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Search for "track_errors PHP".

https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.track-errors

> If enabled, the last error message will always be present in the variable $php_errormsg.

Comment: Thanks! I did honestly do a search and found nothing. Thank you

Comment: This feature has been **DEPRECATED** as of PHP 7.2.0.

Comment: @DavidRefoua that is hilarious. I have just found track errors and just thought it could be useful ... and it is gone. Such is life.

Comment: @BeNice I see what you mean, but considering there are other (and dare I say even _superior_) features such as [`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) that can basically track the same thing _safely_, it's no wonder that the PHP team decided `track_errors_ was redundant ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @BeNice BTW, you might want to use [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php), instead ✌️

Comment: What is the alternative of this ? i can see that $php_errormsg is used in many files.

Comment: More than eleven years into the future, I do search for "track_errors php.ini" – and I find this post.